# Cant play music or youtube videos on arch linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I just got a weird behaviour on arch linux + lxqt.

First it started when playing youtube videos (Tried with firefox and chromium and its the same). Everything loads fine but the video doesn't advance, I press play and nothing happens, the video stays frozen although the button change to a pause button and the title bar shows the playing button.

If I fast forward to any minute, the video will show the right frame but will stay frozen.

Today I just realized that it is also happening when I try to play music on Clementine player. I press play on the file I want but the progress bar doesn't move. Everything looks like it's playing something (play button disappear, title bar shows the song) except the progress bar and the visualizations stays frozen at the point I set it.

I really have no idea where to start to fix this, any suggestions?

Regards.

Comment: Is there any network issue?

Comment: Nop, everything else is working fine and the rest of the computers on that lan have no problems.

Comment: Could be an issue related to audio. You stated that you can't play music. What exactly happens if you try to play music files? (Preferrably try with something like `mpv`, so we can be sure nothing else screws up)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because I had both Pulseaudio and Pipewire packages installed. I completely removed Pipewire and disabled it's systemd services. Made sure all required Pulseaudio packages were installed, restarted and then it worked again.

References:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=273202
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem. I'm running Arch (4.12.3-1-ARCH) + openbox. I've only been using firefox, so I don't know what impact this might have on chromium. I disabled all my plugins, but still no dice.

The problem is driven by the H.264 video codec that enables HTML5 playback.

I was able to play video on youtube, vimeo, etc, by installing:

- gst-libav
- streamer
- gst-plugins-ugly

---

---

Here's my process and rationale:

After digging around, it seems pretty clear this is a Flash/HTML5 issue. I installed the Youtube Flash Player plugin for firefox in order to force youtube to play flash videos (I already had flashplugin installed). I got different errors when I forced youtube to play Flash, so the original issue had to be an HTML5 issue.

After reading the youtube.com/html5 page, it looked like the playback issue might be a H.264 problem.

This link: https://ryanclouser.com/2015/07/16/Arch-Linux-Firefox-H-264-Playback/ suggests a fix can be found by installing:

- gstreamer0.10
- gst-libav
- gst-plugins-good

Other links (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=205792) suggested installing:

- ffmpeg
- gst-plugins-ugly
- gst-libav

Running: 'pacman -Qs ffmpeg' showed I had ffmpeg installed (version 1:3.3.2-2).

I first installed:

- gstreamer
- gst-libav
- gst-plugins-good

However I was still unable to play video from youtube, so I uninstalled all three packages.

After seeing the suggestions on bbs.archlinux to install gst-plugins-ugly, I installed:

- gst-plugins-good
- gst-plugins-bad
- gst-plugins-ugly
- gst-libav
- gstreamer
- ffmpeg2.8

I was then able to play video on youtube and vimeo.

To clean up, I uninstalled:

- ffmpeg2.8
- gst-plugins-good
- gst-plugins-bad

My understanding is that gstreamer has been deprecated, while ffmpeg has taken over. However uninstalling gstreamer broke dependencies for gst-plugins-base-libs, which in term broke dependences for gst-plugins-ugly. So, I kept gstreamer installed. YMMV.

Comment: I think you meant `gstreamer` instaed of `streamer`?